# Why return function with arguments is undefined?

Tags: javascript, return-value, anonymous-function

I tried for many hours but I don't understand why `return` is undefined...

This is my code:

```
var x = 30.858;
var id = 584;

var num_reg = region(x);
if (num_reg == false) {
  num_reg = ripeti_region(x);
}


function ripeti_region(lng) {
  if (lng <= 180) {
    lng = lng - 0.2;
  } else if (lng => -180) {
    lng = lng + 0.2;
  }

  if (region(lng) != false) {
    var x = region(lng);   
    return x;
  } else {
    ripeti_region(lng);
  }
}


function region(lng) {
  if (lng <= 30.458) {
   return id;
  } else {
   return false;
  }
}


alert(num_reg);
```

If I alert `num_reg` I have undefined return, but the code works in fact in function `ripeti_region(lng)` if you add `alert(x)` it prints `var id`

So I would that `num_reg` give like output `var id` value.

This is jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/nj4duw61/

Comment: Because the function doesn't `return` in all cases…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
else {
    ripeti_region(lng);
  }
```

This part of code doesn't return anything.

Probably you wanted to `return  ripeti_region(lng);`

Comment: but when i run "ripeti_region(lng)" it should repeat same function and so if region(lng) != false return x